# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I have the code below:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
matrix = pd.read_table('testGEM.txt')
ID = pd.read_table('test_transcripts.txt', header = None)
ls = ID.values.tolist()
list=[]
for sublist in id:
    for item in sublist:
        list.append(item)
id = tuple(list)
x = matrix[matrix.index.isin(id)]
x.to_csv('test10.out',sep='\t')
```

However, when I run the code, I got a problem saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "map.py", line 7, in <module>
for sublist in id:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: What do you expect `id` to represent in this code? There was a comment (that for some reason was deleted) that suggested you might have intended it to be `ID` instead. `id`, lowercase, is a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: Okay! I see. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

In python, `id` is a built in function described below. You probably wanted to iterate over `ID` in your case instead.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense to me.